# Add html elements in razor view

Tags: c#, razor

I am very new to razor I always workder with aspx pages, I am trying to have a login form with 2 text and a submit button and down of it I am trying to add a square menu with gradients and hoover but I got stuck.

this is my Login.cshtml:

```
@model Magazzino.Models.LoginViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["message"])));
</script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Username)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
}

<div style="background: grey">
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 35%; width: 15%; background: linear-gradient(red, orange);">
    <div style="height: 30%; border: 1px solid;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Contatti", "Contatti")
    </div>
    <div style="height: 30%; border: 1px solid;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Dove Siamo", "DoveSiamo", null, new { @style = "position: relative; top: 90%;" })
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float: right; margin-right: 35%; width: 15%; text-align: right; background: linear-gradient(green, yellow);">
    <div style="height: 30%; border: 1px solid;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Informazioni", "Informazioni")
    </div>
    <div style="height: 30%; border: 1px solid;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Chi Siamo", "ChiSiamo", null, new { @style = "position: relative; top: 90%;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

In this ways google and firefox render the div with the actionlink in a normal way but IE doesn't render the height so I added a layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And now IE, Chrome and Firefox are rendering the div with the action without height, I guess it's not the right way to put HTMl elements that are not linked to the form, but How do I put other HTML elements inside a razor page which has got already a form?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any problems with your HTML markup.  What exactly is the problem?  The description makes it sound like a CSS styling problem, which has nothing to do with server-side view engines.

Comment: the problem is that the background grey only appears if i put it inside the div that encloses the form, if I put it in the div where I need outside the begin form is not appearing because the div is all messed up and It doesn't set the height of the others div.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is mostly css and html problem.

1. - I don't see the closing tag for `<div style="background: grey">`, I would verify that it is closed properly.
2. - You have two floating divs, I would put an extra tag `<div style='clear:both'>` before closing the `<div style="background: grey">` tag. This will clear the floating after that point.
3. - After 1. and 2., if you don't see the grey background, I would suspect that the inner divs covered the background, if so, I would add some padding in the parent tag, for example `<div style="background: grey; padding: 10px;">`